# Can one change the output path of cups pdf printer dynamically

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf, cups-lpd

One can call `lpr` to use cups-pdf printer to print a file to pdf, for instance `foo.txt`

```
lpr -P PDF foo.txt
```

When calling, the printer creates a directory called `PDF` in the `$HOME` directory and creates a file named `foo.pdf`.

[This manual](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110742) shows how to change the printers default directory. I'm wondering whether it is possible however to pass an option to the pdf printer that sets the output path specifically. Something like:

```
lpr -P PDF foo.txt -o bar.pdf
```

Such that only for this one call, the output path is `bar.pdf`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`cups-pdf` is not an extension to cups. All it does is provide a virtual printer which prints PDF files instead of physical sheets of paper. Since every printer has a single output tray where you collect your printed sheets, `cups-pdf` has the default output directory, hence there is no way to mention command line options to `lpr` to print to a different location.

For all the configurations in `cups-pdf`, refer [official documentation](http://www.cups-pdf.de/cups-pdf-CURRENT/README).